# React Native Project stuck at %98 whener clean or build operation on Android Studio , VSCode

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to locally run android project on my windows machine. First after I run

```
    "android": "react-native run-android",
```

this command and " /gradle clean" command are proceed until %98 and it never proceed again and never throw an error.

I tried many solutions such as;

-adb kill and start server

-cold boot on android studio

-change the jcenter() with mavenCentral() and gradlePluginPortal()

but I didn't work.

At the end of the day no matter how I long wait the result same as below .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V0D6.png)

What should I do ?

+UPDATE

I'm sharing build.gradle below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUK3Y.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03t69.png)

Comment: please provide detailed error and application details like react-native version etc

Comment: @ramashishtomar I've added of all information as image